# Fire Emblem Awakening: Do paired units proc "to all allies" abilities with their mate?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

Suppose Chrom and Female Main Unit are paired on the battlefield. Female Main Unit is a Bride and has the Bond ability. Chrom is a Great Lord.

At the start of my turn, Chrom is in front, and Female Main Unit is acting as the "support" unit in the pair. Will Bond proc, even though Female Main Unit isn't ***technically*** on the field? If it does proc, will it affect Chrom, who is occupying the same space as Female Main Unit rather than an adjacent / nearby square?

Finally, does Bond apply to ***Female Main Unit***? The person who has the ability? The text of the ability states:

> Restores 10 HP to all allies within a 3 tile radius at the beginning of the user's Turn. Having multiple users of Bond does not increase the HP regenerated

Technically Female Main Unit is an "ally" of herself, and she's "within 3 tiles" of herself. Does she heal from her own Bond ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, recovery skills like these don't activate if the unit is acting as a support unit. The unit has to be in the front.

In FE, "nearby allies" in skill descriptions mean "same-team units in other tiles". The character with Bond will not receive the heal, and neither will their paired up partner. Other nearby units, paired up or not, will be healed. Basically the same as the Rally skills.

This detail is probably a leftover from how the Rescue mechanic worked in earlier titles. It feels intuitive as an FE veteran.

Comment: Thanks for all of the information. Unfortunately I'm not a FE veteran, myself. I just borrowed Awakening from a friend and was trying to figure out my ideal team :) Since the Pair Up mechanic is incredibly strong I'm planning all of my skills around a "lead" and "support" unit -- e.g., put Dual Guard+ on my support unit but put Renewal on my leader unit. I've been trying to figure out all of the mechanics so I don't make mistakes and screw up my perfect party.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. The games have a few quirks like this, but the skill is alright even if it only heals up to 24 units instead of 26. Generally MU can become a super strong attacker with skills like Galeforce, Luna, and Lifestealer, and saving the skill slot for that purpose might be more useful in endgame. Just my opinion though. :)

Comment: My current strategy involves a FeMU (so I can pass Galeforce to Morgan, creating 4 males with Galeforce), pairing four Galeforce males with four Galeforce females in S-rank pairs, plus a lesbian A-rank dual-Galeforce couple. The units are primarily Wyvern Lords and Dark Fliers (high movement and flying) so each "lead" unit has Aegis to overcome the weakness to ranged. Each lead unit also has Renewal so I don't depend on healers, but I can swap in a few Falcon Knights for healers if I want. The challenge has been picking "support" skills. So far only Dual Guard+ stands out.

Comment: I see! For Normal and Hard difficulties, Dual Guard+ definitely makes a lot of sense. Galeforce is also surprisingly good for support characters - you can defeat three units in a single turn with a pair, and end up leaving the main character to the front. Lancebreaker, Bowbreaker, and Tomebreaker can be rather useful to have ways to deal with weapon types your lead units may struggle with. Make sure you have some answer for enemy mages - a Vengeance + Nosferatu unit worked well for me. (For Lunatic difficulty, there's a lot more restrictions since you can't grind extra gold/EXP.) Good luck!